# How do I disable cipher suite using java.security

Tags: java, security, java-8

How can I disable a particular cipher suite in java.security?

For example, I wish to disable this `SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`.

How should I add it in using the command below?

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, \
EC keySize < 224
```

And finally, how to verify if it is disabled?

Comment: Use [sslscan](https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan) or [TestSSLServer](http://www.bolet.org/TestSSLServer/) to see what ciphers are enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to append the suite name to the end of the line?

According to [the post](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) a full cipher suite name or any part of it could be used as a property value.

So, I presume this should work:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, \
EC keySize < 224, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
```

Comment: Adding full name of the cipher worked for me. But, appending any part of it, say `TLS_RSA` did NOT disable all the ciphers starting with TLS_RSA.

Answer (score -1):

Found what I wanted here.

[Link](https://blog.eveoh.nl/2014/02/tls-ssl-ciphers-pfs-tomcat/)